# LDA as base learner for AdaBoost in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, adaboost

I'm working on multi-class classification using AdaBoost, with the base learner as a discriminant (linear or quadratic). I couldn't find any functionality in scikit-learn or any other library to implement this, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although scikit-learn's `AdaBoostClassifier` allows for a base estimator of your choosing (see [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html)), it requires the estimator to support `sample_weight`. Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py#L429):

```
if not has_fit_parameter(self.base_estimator_, "sample_weight"):
    raise ValueError("%s doesn't support sample_weight."
                     % self.base_estimator_.__class__.__name__)
```

Unfortunately, neither `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` nor `QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis` fall into this category. Here's a toy example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis as QDA
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris = load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target)

clf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=LDA())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You'll see a traceback like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 411, in fit
    return super(AdaBoostClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 128, in fit
    self._validate_estimator()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py", line 429, in _validate_estimator
    % self.base_estimator_.__class__.__name__)
ValueError: LinearDiscriminantAnalysis doesn't support sample_weight.
```

This is a requirement you're not going to get around in scikit-learn. The documentation makes it clear that it's a hard requirement:

> "...Support for sample weighting is required, as well as proper `classes_` and `n_classes_` attributes."

However, if your desire is simply to use an ensemble, you could always use bagging rather than boosting:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LDA())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: I was working on a project, and I wanted to compare the performance of AdaBoost on a dataset with different types of weak learners. I had read somewhere that LDA, QDA, perceptrons etc do come under weak learners, hence this question. I guess I have to use something else then, thank you!